# How to combine MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

How to combine MySQL queries to delete rows on table where column data is equal to SELECT of other table?

I think of:
`DELETE FROM debts WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM payers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `=`, change it to `IN` since the subquery can return multiple rows.

```
DELETE FROM debts WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM payers)
```

But I prefer to `JOIN` the tables than using `IN`.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    debts a
        INNER JOIN payers b
            ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanations, please? Is it ready query or a, b are just placeholders?

Comment: @Ultra `a` and `b` are alias of tables. so instead of writing the full table name, you can use the alias.

Comment: And how to `DELETE` all but not selected from `payers` ?

Comment: change `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` -- `DELETE  a
FROM    debts a
        LEFT JOIN payers b
            ON a.name = b.name WHERE b.name IS NULL`

Comment: But I ask for IN solution

Comment: `JOIN` are more efficient than `IN` in mysql.